# Why wont SharePoint accept an (app only) access token from login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, sharepoint-online

I've been implementing a script that uploads a file to SharePoint.
I have a `client_id` and a `client_secret` and I can successfully pull access tokens from both:

- `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
- `https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{tenant-id}/tokens/OAuth/2`

But SharePoint only likes the access token from `accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net` and I would like to understand why.

Using the access token from `login.microsoftonline.com` gives the following error response:

```
status: 401
body: {"error_description": "ID3035: The request was not valid or is malformed."}
headers: {
  "x-cache" "CONFIG_NOCACHE",
  "x-ariacollectorurl" "https://eu-mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0",
  "x-databoundary" "EU",
  "x-msedge-ref" "Ref A: *** Ref B: *** Ref C: 2024-01-18T08:12:48Z",
  "x-ms-diagnostics" "3001000;reason=\"There has been an error authenticating the request.\";category=\"invalid_client\"",
  "x-ms-invokeapp" "1; RequireReadOnly",
  "x-content-type-options" "nosniff",
  "sprequestduration" "25",
  "content-length" "74",
  "www-authenticate" "Bearer realm=\"d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a\",client_id=\"00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000\",trusted_issuers=\"00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*,0C538Cfd-6795-4147-9694-1BBC07C2B642@*,https://sts.windows.net/*/,https://login.microsoftonline.com/*/v2.0,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@53185463-2120-46f2-94ab-4d605a94eb8c\",authorization_uri=\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize\"",
  "sprequestguid" "dcfc75ba-b65e-4d9e-be2a-59f572d499af",
  "x-networkstatistics" "0,531568,0,0,292231,0,451786",
  "p3p" "CP=\"ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI\"",
  "microsoftsharepointteamservices" "16.0.0.24503",
  "x-1dscollectorurl" "https://eu-mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/",
  ":status" "401",
  "date" "Thu, 18 Jan 2024 08:12:48 GMT",
  "spiislatency" "3",
  "request-id" "dcfc75ba-b65e-4d9e-be2a-59f572d499af",
  "x-powered-by" "ASP.NET",
  "cache-control" "private",
  "ms-cv" "****"
}
```

Below are examples of the access token payloads from both providers:

**login.microsoftonline.com**:

```
{
  "aud": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a/",
  "iat": 1705647949,
  "nbf": 1705647949,
  "exp": 1705651849,
  "aio": "RnVpdGdH***kdPV2NkNThzYVdjMwo=",
  "app_displayname": "My App",
  "appid": "f3a7cbdc-6abc-48a1-9557-c23228ed7f6b",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a/",
  "idtyp": "app",
  "oid": "36e55927-0f14-4d0d-a4d1-9a06d7188e41",
  "rh": "0.AR1A7***AAAAAAPEPbgAAAAAAAAEFAAA.",
  "sid": "99d2c090-a7fd-447c-a3ce-b552ff45b3d9",
  "sub": "36e55927-0f14-4d0d-a4d1-9a06d7188e41",
  "tid": "d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a",
  "uti": "2BKsNj***bbovXNpGOAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

**accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net**:

```
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/contoso.sharepoint.com@d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a",
  "iss": "00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a",
  "iat": 1705647949,
  "nbf": 1705647949,
  "exp": 1705651849,
  "identityprovider": "00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a",
  "nameid": "f3a7cbdc-6abc-48a1-9557-c23228ed7f6b@d12d11b1-0ad7-4e14-9385-3892b5d6b09a",
  "oid": "36e55927-0f14-4d0d-a4d1-9a06d7188e41",
  "sub": "36e55927-0f14-4d0d-a4d1-9a06d7188e41",
  "trustedfordelegation": "false"
}
```

It feels more "right" to use `login.microsoftonline.com`, because this seems to be what the online documentation usually refers to.

**Notice:** UUID's have been replaced and other fields have been scrambled and/or censored to maintain the "look and feel" but hide potentially sensitive information. UUID's spanning across HTTP response and the two access tokens are still matching even though they are replaced.